# Can onSaveInstanceState(...) be used when switching between activities?

Tags: android, android-activity

I do have 2 activities A (contains a button that redirects to A and a text input) and B (contains a button the redirects to A) and **I was trying to switch from one to another but also to keep the text value** from A.

I was trying to save the text value in a Bundle using onSaveInstanceState(...) but it simply didn't work.

Here are the steps I do:

1. (on A) add some text
2. in A, implement onSaveInstanceState(...) and save the value of text in Bundle
3. (on B) click the button that points back to A
4. (on A) the stored value is gone (also the Bundle sent to onCreate(...) is null)

To my surprise when I'm in A and change the orientation the value is stored (and the Bundle sent to onCreate(...) is not null)

Did I miss something?

Comment: You can use SharedPrefs or you can pass data along with Intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.

`onSaveInstanceState` is meant to save the instance state during things like:

- Memory pressure
- Screen rotation
- Whenever the system decides to stop the activity and resume it later (e.g. it moves to the background, get's forgotten by the user, and later is being picked up again).

Further reading is available [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html).

You should store those values you want to keep in [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), for example during your `onPause` call.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that the onSaveInstanceState method is used ONLY when the activity is destroyed by the system (either upon rotation or other "system constraints")

Answer (score 0):

No you can not use `onSaveInstanceState()` while switching between activities.

`onSaveInstanceState()` Called to retrieve per-instance state from an activity before being killed so that the state can be restored in onCreate(Bundle) or onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle) (the Bundle populated by this method will be passed to both).

This method is called before an activity may be killed so that when it comes back some time in the future it can restore its state. For example, if activity B is launched in front of activity A, and at some point activity A is killed to reclaim resources, activity A will have a chance to save the current state of its user interface via this method so that when the user returns to activity A, the state of the user interface can be restored via onCreate(Bundle) or onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle).

You can get more idea on Android Developer pages:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)